# Only one TestResult folder with MSTest?

Tags: mstest

MSTest seems to be creating 25 folders for TestResults, is there a reason for creating 25 and not just 1? If not can I change it to 1?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual studio, go to Tools->Options and look for Test Tools on the left. Under Test Tools, there is a Test Execution option. In there you can change the number of Test Results.

Here's a visual of that process:

http://arcware.net/limit-the-number-of-old-test-results-with-vs2008/

The default is 25.

Comment: Setting it to one, makes MSTest only create two folders, strange... :-)

Comment: The link you gave has now moved to: http://arcware.net/2007/12/10/limit-the-number-of-old-test-results-with-vs2008/